# For what s does the series converge $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{(-1)^nn^s}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{(-1)^nn^s}$$

For what $s>0$ does the series converge

My try:

The  $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n^s}=0$ if $s\geq\frac{1}{2}$ and thus the series is also decreasing series and it converges.

Comment: @vitamind It is Leibnitz criteria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $n\in\Bbb N$,$$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n}{(-1)^nn^s}=\frac{(-1)^n}{\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n\right)n^s}.$$If $s>-\frac12$, then the sequence $\left(\frac1{\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n\right)n^s}\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is decreasing and it converges to $0$; therefore, your series converges.

Otherwise, you don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n\right)n^s}=0$, and therefore your series diverges.

Comment: I did the same process as you but got:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{(\sqrt{n+1}*n^s+\sqrt{n}*n^s)} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{2s+1}+n^{2s}}+\sqrt{n^{2s+1}}}$$ And then I divided both numerator and denominator by the biggest fraction which is $n^{(2s+1)/2}$

Comment: But I got $s\geq \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: That is when $\frac{2s+1}{2}>1$

Comment: Because in the numerator I then got $\frac{1}{n^{(2s+1)/2}}$

Comment: What matters is that $\frac{2s+1}2>0$, not that $\frac{2s+1}2>1$, beacuse it's when $\frac{2s+1}2>0$ that we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{(2s+1)/2}=\infty$, and therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^{(2s+1)/2}}=0$.

Comment: Carlos Santos, can I ask you, as a profesor, how many points would you give out of 25 for correct process except that the mistake where $>1$ and not $>0$ ?

Comment: Somewhere from 15 to 20.

Comment: Would the same process also satisfy that the series is absolutely convergant, because root test and ratio test do not work in that case ?

Comment: In order to get absolute convergence, one must have $\frac{2s+1}2>1$.